# How to set random animation on changing Tab Panel in sencha touch 2?

Tags: animation, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, tabpanel

I'm still new to sencha touch 2 and currently I'm stuck at how to set different animation each

time user switch between tab panels. Can anyone give me some hints how to accomplish this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a big hint :

```
Ext.define("App.view.Main", {
  extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',

  config: {
    fullscreen: true,
    layout: {
      animation: 'slide'
    },
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    items:[{
      xtype:'panel',
      iconCls: 'home',
      title:'Tab 1',
      html:'Tab1'
    },{
      xtype:'panel',
      iconCls: 'user',
      title:'Tab 2',
      html:'Tab2'
    },{
      xtype:'panel',
      iconCls: 'info',
      title:'Tab 3',
      html:'Tab3'
    }],
    listeners:{
      activeitemchange:function(){
        this.getLayout().setAnimation(['slide','fade','cover','reveal','pop', 'flip'][Math.floor(Math.random()*6)]);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Basically, when the users switch cards, it'll set a new random animation for the tabpanel's layout amongst the ones in `['slide','fade','cover','reveal','pop', 'flip']`;

Feel free to contribute by adding the handling of the direction parameter

**[UPDATE] handle direction**

```
listeners:{
  activeitemchange:function(){
    var anim_with_direction = ['slide','cover','reveal'],
        anim_without_direciton = ['fade','pop', 'flip'],
        anims = anim_with_direction.concat(anim_without_direciton),
        anim,
        type = anims[0],
        direction;
    if(anim_with_direction.indexOf(type) != -1){
      direction = ['left','right','up','down'][Math.floor(Math.random()*4)];
      anim = {type:type,direction:direction};
    }else{ 
      anim = {type:type};
    }
    this.getLayout().setAnimation(anim);
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the green check sign then ;)

Comment: really sorry but can I ask you the method to set the direction in sencha. I'm using setDirection but it didn't work

Comment: It'll be more than a hint then but sure. Let me 10 minutes and I'll update the answer.

Comment: I think next time I will change 'hint' to 'solution' lol. Thank you so much :D